# Convert sql trigger with clr trigger

Tags: c#, sql-server, triggers, clr, sqlclr

I am new to CLR and I want to convert a trigger created in sql server with a clr trigger instead as I am in the process of learning clr.

This is the current code for trigger in SMO:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_tblAircraft_ForInsert
ON tblAircraft
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    Declare @ID int
    Select @ID=AircraftID from inserted
    Declare @NrOfAircraft int
    Select @NrOfAircraft=AircraftUnits from inserted

    Insert into tblAircraftOrderAudit
    values('New aircraft order for ' + Cast(@NrOfAircraft as nvarchar(5)) + ' aircraft with ID = ' + Cast(@ID as nvarchar(5)) + ' was added at ' + Cast(GetDate() as nvarchar(20)))
    END
```

This is how far I have come with my clr code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class Triggers
{        
    // Enter existing table or view for the target and uncomment the attribute line
    [SqlTrigger(Name="SqlTriggerAircraftOrderAudit", Target="tblAircraft", Event="FOR INSERT, UPDATE")]
    public static void SqlTriggerAircraftOrderAudit ()
    {
        Int32 ID;
        Int32 NrOfAircraft;
        SqlCommand command;
        SqlTriggerContext triggContext = SqlContext.TriggerContext;
        SqlPipe pipe = SqlContext.Pipe;
        SqlDataReader reader;

        using (SqlConnection connection
            = new SqlConnection(@"context connection=true"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM INSERTED;",
               connection);
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        ID = (Int32)reader[0];
        NrOfAircraft = (Int32)reader[1];
        reader.Close();

        SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Trigger FIRED");
    }
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there a question in that? or are you just looking for someone to double check your work?

Comment: Sorry for that, as I have poor knowledge about CLR triggers, the above CLR code is how far I have been able to take it, so if I want to recreate the trigger that I created in SQL server how would I go ahead to do the semin CLR trigger code?

Comment: Based on this and your other recent SQLCLR questions it is clear that you are currently learning both .NET and SQL Server, based on mistakes with terminology, SQL Server concepts, and C# concepts. You are learning these in the wrong order: SQLCLR is using .NET within SQL Server, so you need to have a better grasp of both C# and T-SQL before moving on to the advanced topic of SQLCLR. When you have a better understanding of both, then take a look at a series of articles I am writing about SQLCLR: [Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/) (free registration required).